# Finally i created a full functinality Search_bar, but it only searches when i press the Enter Button, after i type on the search bar,

Tags: flutter, dart

Finally I created a full functionality Search bar, but it only searches when I press the Enter Button, after I type on the search bar, I Want the search bar fetches data immediately while I type without I press Enter button,, if you want I add my full code.

Comment: Show relevant code

Comment: In the background, autocomplete is sending multiple search queries, receiving results, and displaying them.  If you haven't made that feature, or included a library, you have a simple form submit.  Since you tagged this question with flutter and dart, perhaps you want: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of implementing the search-while-typing is using a `TextField` widget and implement the `onChanged` method:

```dart
TextField(
  //...
  onChanged: (String value){
    // Search while you type logic...
  }
  //...
)
```